# Отправка ежечасных уведомлений пользователям с учетом таймзоны

Tags: postgresql, golang

Всем привет! пишу небольшой проект, и хочу встроить туда ежечасную отправку уведомлений пользователям в заданных им границах и с учетом введенной временной зоны. В качестве базы используется Postgres, в качестве бэкенда golang. Пользователь вводит свою временную зону в формате числа, она сохраняется в базу(с умножением на -1, иначе работает некорректно) в текстовую ячейку(тут можно число преобразовывать в что-то вроде Europe/Berlin, но это не принципиально на мой взгляд). после этого пользователь вводит начало и конец временного промежутка в своем часовом поясе, в который он хочет получать уведомления(ввести необходимо только часы), все это сохраняется в базу. каждый час запускается ждоба, которая выбирает всех пользователей, которым нужно отправить уведомление. схема базы и запрос прилагаю:

```
users
+----+----+-------+-----+
| id | tz | start | end |
+----+----+-------+-----+
|  1 | -3 |    10 |  20 |
|  2 |  5 |     8 |  22 |
+----+----+-------+-----+
```

```
select * from users where start <= (select date_part('hour', (select (NOW() AT TIME zone "tz") from users))) and 
end >= (select date_part('hour', (select (NOW() AT TIME zone "tz") from users)))
```

это работает, но выглядит довольно громоздко. может быть есть вариант сделать запрос аккуратнее или изначально иначе организовать хранение данных?
буду рад любым идеям и предложениям!

Comment: Надеюсь вы знаете что есть тайм-зоны с нецелым смещением по времени? "The offsets are usually a whole number of hours, but a few zones are offset by an additional 30 or 45 minutes, such as in India, South Australia and Nepal."

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_between.asp

Comment: *это работает, но выглядит довольно громоздко* Ну вообще-то два нестрогих неравенства - это просто расписанный оператор BETWEEN. Тогда вместо двух копий выражения будет одна, и всё вроде шоколадно...

Comment: И вообще-то Europe/Berlin лучше числа. Хотя бы из-за летнего/зимнего времени

Comment: про нецелые таймзоны знаю и это будет учтено. про переход на сохранение таймзоны в формате  Europe/Berlin согласен, сделаю.

Comment: с оператором BETWEEN запрос начинает работать на порядок медленнее(85мс против 926мс). возможно, это получится решить это индексами, подумаю в этом напрвавлении

Comment: я бы хранил: не время start, end, tz, а время start (в UTC) и число часов сколько можно слать. тогда выборка была бы в разы проще и не нужно было бы с таймзоной работой... простейший запрос

Comment: рассылки буду на ежедневной основе, поэтому хранить время не получится. а если записывать часы в UTC, то нужна будет серьезная логика на случай перехода через 00

Answer (score 0):

Если ты сделаешь хранение `Europe/Berlin`, то это автоматически решит проблему нецелых смещений и летнего времени.

```
create table tbl (
  tz text,
  start_h int,
  end_h int
);

insert into tbl (tz, start_h, end_h)
  values ('America/Los_Angeles', 8, 16);
insert into tbl (tz, start_h, end_h)
  values ('Europe/Berlin', 8, 16);


with current_hour as (
  SELECT 
    name tz, 
    date_part('hour', now() at time zone name) as h 
  FROM 
    pg_timezone_names
)
select 
    *
from 
   tbl 
   inner join current_hour using (tz)
where 
   current_hour.h between start_h and end_h
```

Причём список поддерживаемых таймзон прямо у Постгриса можно взять

```
select * FROM pg_timezone_names
```